# Elastic search: How to finding exact value

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the **ElasticSearch version 7.4** with Java API Client.
I am facing an issue raleted to finding exact value:

My mapping:

> elasticsearch.address.mapping={"properties":{"address":{"type":"text","analyzer":
> "folding"},"id":{"type":"long"},"ward_name":{"type":"text","analyzer":"folding"},
> "**address_number**":{"type":"text", "index" : "not_analyzed"}}}

My java code:

> BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
> boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("address_number", "6"));

I have got some results:

- 6/12
- 6/10
- 6
- 16/6

I only want to get the address number **6**, and will skip another results

Please help me on this. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, ES actually advises you to **not** use (termQuery) against TextFields, which address_number is:

> Term query edit
>
> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.
>
> You can use the term query to find documents based on a precise value
> such as a price, a product ID, or a username.
>
> **Avoid using the term query for text fields**

> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
> analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
> difficult.
>
> To search text field values, **use the match query instead**.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query

You should use match instead:

Example:

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery("address_number", "6")
```

Comment: Hi @SMA,  I try boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("address_number","6")); the results contains 216/6, 16/6, 6/6, 56/6, 6, ........

Comment: You should use `keyword` fields if you need exact match